# Printing has characters cut off

Tags: org-mode, print

When I print from emacs an org mode file, I get very little left margin and there's no margin on the right and a character is cut off on the right from each line.

`ps-paper-type` is set to a4. `ps-left-margin` and `ps-right-margin` are set to 56.69291338582677.

I just want every letter to be printed without being cut off. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you print an ordinary text file, `*.txt`? If the same thing then remove mention of Org mode, to reduce the search space for the problem.

Comment: Provide a recipe for just what you're doing, to reproduce it - what print commands etc., starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say what platform you're on, and whether you're using any OS print commands etc. IOW, say exactly what you're doing.